# Haskell: Unexpected result on list comprehension evaluation

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm just learning some Haskell and while playing with list comprehensions in the repl I can't understand how the tuple `("bird", 4)` is generated in the following code:

```
*Main> :{
*Main| [(x, y) | x <- ["cat", "dog", "bird"]
*Main|         , y <- [1..length x]]
*Main| :}
[("cat",1),("cat",2),("cat",3),("dog",1),("dog",2),("dog",3),("bird",1),("bird",2),("bird",3),("bird",4)]
```

As of my understanding, the length of `x` is never bigger than `3`, I would expect to see three tuples of `bird` as they are three for `cat` and three for `dog`.

Why does this happen? What does Haskell sees?

Comment: If `x` is `"bird"`, then `length x` is `4` (since bird has four characters).

Comment: Oh! I get it, `x` refers to each element, not the whole list! I totally misunderstood that.

Comment: you should see `x` as a *loop variable* (if we would write it imperatively), so indeed `x` refers to an individual item, *not* the list of strings.

Comment: [read list comprehensions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.7C) as "list of (x,y)s for x in ...; for y in ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: `x` takes as value the **items** of the list, **not** the list itself.

You can see list comprehension in Haskell like it is done in Python:

```
[(x, y) | x <- ["cat", "dog", "bird"]
        , y <- [1..length x]]
```

is equivalent to:

```
[(x,y) for x in ["cat", "dog", "bird"] for y in range(1, 1+len(x))]
```

Or in a precedural way:

```
result = []
for x in ["cat", "dog", "bird"]:
    for y in range(1, 1+len(x)):
        result.append((x,y))
```

So we iterate with `x` over the list `["cat", "dog", "bird"]`, and then for every value `x`, we iterate over `range(1, 1+len(x))` with `y`. For the last item of the list, `"bird"` it thus means that the `length` / `len` of `"bird"` is four (since bird is a word with four characters). And thus `y` will iterate four times for bird.

In case you want to take the `minimum` of the lengths of `x`, you can use:

```
[(x, y) | x <- ["cat", "dog", "bird"]
        , y <- [1..minimum (map length) ["cat", "dog", "bird"]]]
```

In case you want to take the `length` of the list of strings itself, you can use `length` of that list, so:

```
[(x, y) | x <- ["cat", "dog", "bird"]
        , y <- [1..length ["cat", "dog", "bird"]]]
```